# Javascript Migration to Import/Export Do I Have to Rewrite Every Script Simultaneously?

Tags: ecmascript-6

My website, started in 1993, contains thousands of pages and hundreds of Javascript files. These are written in the 1990s style with each individual Javascript file imported by the HTML page, for example:

```html
      <script src="/jscripts/js20/http.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <script src="/jscripts/util.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <script src="/genealogy.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
```

genealogy.js depends upon both http.js and util.js and util.js depends upon http.js. FYI the specific page is at https://www.jamescobban.net/genealogy.php?lang=en and is documented at https://github.com/jcobban/Genealogy/wiki/TopLevel-genealogy.php

Now at the level of individual files I understand what needs to be done. I have experimented editing one library file and one application file that depends on that one library file and run the combination past eslint and it is happy. In the "library" files I insert "export " in front of everything those libraries are exporting, basically most functions and consts. At the front of util.js and genealogy.js I add the import for those specific resources that they reference, using the error messages from eslint to guide me. I then delete all of the now redundant `<script>` statements from the one HTML page that uses genealogy.js.

That is fine for learning and testing. I can obviously make *one* page work. But do I have to change *every* one of the thousands of files in my site simultaneously once I start this process? For example if I add the import statements to some but not all of the hundreds of Javascript files with dependencies, and I do not delete every single now redundant `<script>` tag will my site fail? Will the browser complain if a "library" file is included by HTML as well as by Javascript import or will it be included twice? Will the addition of export statements to library files make it impossible for application scripts that are still coded to ES3 to access the resources they did when the library file did not have the export statements?

I have tried experimenting by renaming all of the files which use import and export.  So at the top of my application script I have:

```js
import HTTP from "../jscripts/js20/http6.js";
import {iframe, actMouseOverHelp, openFrame, openSignon, debug, args,
        getOffsetLeft, getOffsetTop, popupAlert, show,
        showHelp, hideHelp, helpDiv, helpElt, keyDown,
        eltMouseOver, eltMouseOut}
            from "../jscripts/util6.js";
import {capitalize} from "../jscripts/CommonForm6.js";
import Cookie from "../jscripts/Cookie6.js";
```

This satisfies eslint but fails at run time.

I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default in the library script CommonForm.js.  The line it is complaining about is:

```js
import HTTP from "../jscripts/js20/http6.js";
```

Which puzzles me because that is exactly the same as the first import from my application script.

Comment: Before making the change you should try to make the change easier - could you be _generating_ all of those HTML files, using some kind of templating? If you're currently hand-maintaining thousands of files that could be a big win.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I am generating the HTML from templates but there are still 528 template files each of which contains the set of <script> tags specific to the class of pages.  That still seems to require that I change all 538 template files and 291 javascript files simultaneously.  That can be done by grep | sed if I get the migration script perfect.  Then I have to verify the functionality of all of those 538 classes of pages before I can deploy ANY change to the production site.  So far I have not succeeded in getting ONE page to work.

Comment: [Getting around comment max size limit] Specifically for each class of page I apparently must move all of the information currently specified in <script> tags into the page specific initialization script and remove it from the template.  I do not think I can do that with an automated script because there are hundreds of different classes of page.  See https://github.com/jcobban/Genealogy/wiki

Comment: Perhaps I should specify my query more explicitly.   What techniques are available to permit me to migrate a subset of my pages to exploit ES2015 import and export? I like the functionality as it has caught sloppy implementations in my interfaces.  But that still leaves me the problem of changing 538 template files and 291 javascript files which it is physically impossible to perform and test overnight.  It will take me months to make all of those changes and verify that nothing has been broken in the mean time, during which I can do nothing to address any other issues that arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate the precision in design which ES2015 and above permit.  Running eslint over the ES2015 versions of my code has detected several dubious design issues.

To support migrating one application at a time I implemented a second directory containing ES2015 versions of all of the JavaScript files which are included by individual pages to obtain common services.  Fortunately I had already isolated all of those scripts in their own folder of the web site, `jscripts`.  So I created a parallel folder `jscripts6` in which all of the ES2015 versions of these support files are stored.

So the ES3 version of a page uses a template which includes library routines from folder jscripts, for example:

```html
    <script src="/jscripts/js20/http.js" type="application/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/jscripts/util.js" type="application/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/jscripts/CommonForm.js" type="application/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/jscripts/Cookie.js" type="application/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/FamilyTree/Person.js" type="application/javascript">
    </script>
```

while the ES2015 version of the template only includes

```html
    <script src="/FamilyTree/Person.js" type="module">
    </script>
```

and the one file Person.js is rewritten to import the functionality by:

```js
import {HTTP} from "../jscripts6/js20/http.js";
import {iframe, actMouseOverHelp, openFrame, openSignon, debug, args,
        getOffsetLeft, getOffsetTop, popupAlert, show,
        showHelp, hideHelp, helpElt, helpDiv, keyDown,
        simpleMouseOver, eltMouseOut}
            from "../jscripts6/util.js";
import {capitalize} from "../jscripts6/CommonForm.js";
import {Cookie} from "../jscripts6/Cookie.js";
```

I can now migrate one application script at a time from ES3 to ES2015 while the un-migrated scripts continue to access the functionality in the legacy directory.